# iOS 8 MAC address randomization

Tags: wifi, ios

I was reading [this news](http://techcrunch.com/2014/06/09/apple-makes-it-harder-for-in-store-marketers-to-track-you-in-ios-8/?ncid=rss), and it got me thinking: will this be a hard setting or configurable?

How can I configure or understand how this works so I can work with services that recognize my MAC address for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to answer as it will only display as random when you're not connected. If you get connected (using a password for example) the **real mac-address** will be shown to the router.

It's just a randomize function for **unknown networks**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not up-to-date with how it works exactly. But I've heard that the MAC address is only randomized when it's looking for all available WiFi networks. When an user selects a network to connect with, your non-randomized standard MAC address is used. I think this wouldn't be any problem.